# ImGui Vulkan Validation Layer Error when undocking

Tags: c++, vulkan, imgui

When using ImGui for Vulkan with `imgui_impl_vulkan.cpp`, `imgui_impl_glfw.cpp` and their respective headers I get no validation layers errors, but when I am using the `docking` branch and undock or in other words when I detach the ImGui window from the main Vulkan window (as you may guess created with GLFW), I get this error:

```
validation layer: vkCmdDrawIndexed(): RenderPasses incompatible between active render pass w/ VkRenderPass 0x243b910000000054[] and pipeline state object w/ VkRenderPass 0x731f0f000000000a[] Attachment 0 is not compatible with 0: They have different formats.. The Vulkan spec states: The current render pass must be compatible with the renderPass member of the VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo structure specified when creating the VkPipeline bound to VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS.
```

My command buffers are created like this:

```
void createCommandBuffers() {
    commandBuffers.resize(swapChainFramebuffers.size());

    VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo allocInfo = {};
    allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    allocInfo.commandPool = commandPool;
    allocInfo.level = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY;
    allocInfo.commandBufferCount = (uint32_t)commandBuffers.size();

    if (vkAllocateCommandBuffers(device, &allocInfo, commandBuffers.data()) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to allocate command buffers!");
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < commandBuffers.size(); i++) {
        VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo = {};
        beginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;

        if (vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[i], &beginInfo) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to begin recording command buffer!");
        }

        VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassInfo = {};
        renderPassInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
        renderPassInfo.renderPass = renderPass;
        renderPassInfo.framebuffer = swapChainFramebuffers[i];
        renderPassInfo.renderArea.offset = { 0, 0 };
        renderPassInfo.renderArea.extent = swapChainExtent;

        VkClearValue clearColor = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
        renderPassInfo.clearValueCount = 1;
        renderPassInfo.pClearValues = &clearColor;

        vkCmdBeginRenderPass(commandBuffers[i], &renderPassInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

        vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, graphicsPipeline);

        VkBuffer vertexBuffers[] = { vertexBuffer };
        VkDeviceSize offsets[] = { 0 };
        vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffers[i], 0, 1, vertexBuffers, offsets);

        vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(commandBuffers[i], indexBuffer, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT16);

        vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout, 0, 1, &descriptorSets[i], 0, nullptr);

        vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffers[i], static_cast<uint32_t>(indices.size()), 1, 0, 0, 0);

        // Bind Dear Imgui pipeline to draw UI elements inside UI box
        if (isImGuiWindowCreated)
        {
            ImGui_ImplVulkan_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData(), commandBuffers[i]);
        }

        vkCmdEndRenderPass(commandBuffers[i]);

        if (vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[i]) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to record command buffer!");
        }
    }
    isImGuiWindowCreated = false;
}
```

I initialize ImGui like this:

```
void initImGui(float width, float height) {
    QueueFamilyIndices Indices = findQueueFamilies(physicalDevice);

    // Setup Dear ImGui context
    IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
    ImGui::CreateContext();
    ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO(); (void)io;
    io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_DockingEnable;
    io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_ViewportsEnable;
    //io.Fonts->AddFontFromFileTTF("../../Assets/Fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf", 16.0f);

    // When viewports are enabled we tweak WindowRounding/WindowBg so platform windows can look identical to regular ones.
    ImGuiStyle& style = ImGui::GetStyle();
    if (io.ConfigFlags & ImGuiConfigFlags_ViewportsEnable)
    {
        style.WindowRounding = 0.0f;
        style.Colors[ImGuiCol_WindowBg].w = 1.0f;
    }

    io.DisplaySize = ImVec2(width, height);
    io.DisplayFramebufferScale = ImVec2(1.0f, 1.0f);

    // Setup Platform/Renderer bindings
    ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForVulkan(window, true);
    ImGui_ImplVulkan_InitInfo init_info = {};
    init_info.Instance = instance;
    init_info.PhysicalDevice = physicalDevice;
    init_info.Device = device;
    init_info.QueueFamily = Indices.graphicsFamily.value();
    init_info.Queue = presentQueue;
    init_info.PipelineCache = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    init_info.DescriptorPool = descriptorPool;
    init_info.Allocator = NULL;
    init_info.MinImageCount = 2;
    init_info.ImageCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(swapChainImages.size());
    init_info.CheckVkResultFn = NULL;
    ImGui_ImplVulkan_Init(&init_info, renderPass);

    // Setup Dear ImGui style
    ImGui::StyleColorsDark();

    VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer = beginSingleTimeCommands();
    ImGui_ImplVulkan_CreateFontsTexture(commandBuffer);
    endSingleTimeCommands(commandBuffer);
    ImGui_ImplVulkan_DestroyFontUploadObjects();
}
```

This is the definition of `beginSingleTimeCommands()`

```
VkCommandBuffer beginSingleTimeCommands() {
    VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo allocInfo = {};
    allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    allocInfo.level = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY;
    allocInfo.commandPool = commandPool;
    allocInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;

    VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer;
    vkAllocateCommandBuffers(device, &allocInfo, &commandBuffer);

    VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo = {};
    beginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
    beginInfo.flags |= VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT;

    vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer, &beginInfo);

    return commandBuffer;
}
```

I don't know how to tackle this as I have already tried creating different `RenderPasses` for ImGui and the main application, I also tried creating different `CommandBuffers` and that hasn't solved the problem either. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Here is how I create the `RenderPass`:

```
void createRenderPass() {
    VkAttachmentDescription colorAttachment = {};
    colorAttachment.format = swapChainImageFormat;
    colorAttachment.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    colorAttachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
    colorAttachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    colorAttachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    colorAttachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    colorAttachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    colorAttachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;

    VkAttachmentReference colorAttachmentRef = {};
    colorAttachmentRef.attachment = 0;
    colorAttachmentRef.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

    VkSubpassDescription subpass = {};
    subpass.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
    subpass.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
    subpass.pColorAttachments = &colorAttachmentRef;

    VkSubpassDependency dependency = {};
    dependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
    dependency.dstSubpass = 0;
    dependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
    dependency.srcAccessMask = 0;
    dependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
    dependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;

    VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderPassInfo = {};
    renderPassInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
    renderPassInfo.attachmentCount = 1;
    renderPassInfo.pAttachments = &colorAttachment;
    renderPassInfo.subpassCount = 1;
    renderPassInfo.pSubpasses = &subpass;
    renderPassInfo.dependencyCount = 1;
    renderPassInfo.pDependencies = &dependency;

    if (vkCreateRenderPass(device, &renderPassInfo, nullptr, &renderPass) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create render pass!");
    }
}
```

And the `GraphicsPipeline`, I use the same `RenderPass` for both ImGui and the main window: `renderPass`

```
void createGraphicsPipeline() {
    auto vertShaderCode = readFile("Shaders\\vert.spv");
    auto fragShaderCode = readFile("Shaders\\frag.spv");

    VkShaderModule vertShaderModule = createShaderModule(vertShaderCode);
    VkShaderModule fragShaderModule = createShaderModule(fragShaderCode);

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo vertShaderStageInfo = {};
    vertShaderStageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    vertShaderStageInfo.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT;
    vertShaderStageInfo.module = vertShaderModule;
    vertShaderStageInfo.pName = "main";

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo fragShaderStageInfo = {};
    fragShaderStageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    fragShaderStageInfo.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT;
    fragShaderStageInfo.module = fragShaderModule;
    fragShaderStageInfo.pName = "main";

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo shaderStages[] = { vertShaderStageInfo, fragShaderStageInfo };

    VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo vertexInputInfo = {};
    vertexInputInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VERTEX_INPUT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;

    auto bindingDescription = Vertex::getBindingDescription();
    auto attributeDescriptions = Vertex::getAttributeDescriptions();

    vertexInputInfo.vertexBindingDescriptionCount = 1;
    vertexInputInfo.vertexAttributeDescriptionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(attributeDescriptions.size());
    vertexInputInfo.pVertexBindingDescriptions = &bindingDescription;
    vertexInputInfo.pVertexAttributeDescriptions = attributeDescriptions.data();

    VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo inputAssembly = {};
    inputAssembly.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    inputAssembly.topology = VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST;
    inputAssembly.primitiveRestartEnable = VK_FALSE;

    VkViewport viewport = {};
    viewport.x = 0.0f;
    viewport.y = 0.0f;
    viewport.width = (float)swapChainExtent.width;
    viewport.height = (float)swapChainExtent.height;
    viewport.minDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.maxDepth = 1.0f;

    VkRect2D scissor = {};
    scissor.offset = { 0, 0 };
    scissor.extent = swapChainExtent;

    VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo viewportState = {};
    viewportState.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VIEWPORT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    viewportState.viewportCount = 1;
    viewportState.pViewports = &viewport;
    viewportState.scissorCount = 1;
    viewportState.pScissors = &scissor;

    VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rasterizer = {};
    rasterizer.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    rasterizer.depthClampEnable = VK_FALSE;
    rasterizer.rasterizerDiscardEnable = VK_FALSE;
    rasterizer.polygonMode = VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL;
    rasterizer.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    rasterizer.cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT;
    rasterizer.frontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_CLOCKWISE;
    rasterizer.depthBiasEnable = VK_FALSE;

    VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo multisampling = {};
    multisampling.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_MULTISAMPLE_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    multisampling.sampleShadingEnable = VK_FALSE;
    multisampling.rasterizationSamples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;

    VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState colorBlendAttachment = {};
    // Original.
    colorBlendAttachment.colorWriteMask = VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_R_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_G_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_B_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_A_BIT;
    colorBlendAttachment.blendEnable = VK_TRUE;
    colorBlendAttachment.srcColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_SRC_ALPHA;
    colorBlendAttachment.dstColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA;
    colorBlendAttachment.colorBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD;
    colorBlendAttachment.srcAlphaBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_SRC_ALPHA;
    colorBlendAttachment.dstAlphaBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA;
    colorBlendAttachment.alphaBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_SUBTRACT;
    // For ImGui.
    /*colorBlendAttachment.blendEnable = VK_TRUE;
    colorBlendAttachment.srcColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_SRC_ALPHA;
    colorBlendAttachment.dstColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA;
    colorBlendAttachment.colorBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD;
    colorBlendAttachment.srcAlphaBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA;
    colorBlendAttachment.dstAlphaBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ZERO;
    colorBlendAttachment.alphaBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD;
    colorBlendAttachment.colorWriteMask = VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_R_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_G_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_B_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_A_BIT;*/

    VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo colorBlending = {};
    colorBlending.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_COLOR_BLEND_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    colorBlending.logicOpEnable = VK_FALSE;
    colorBlending.logicOp = VK_LOGIC_OP_COPY;
    colorBlending.attachmentCount = 1;
    colorBlending.pAttachments = &colorBlendAttachment;
    colorBlending.blendConstants[0] = 0.0f;
    colorBlending.blendConstants[1] = 0.0f;
    colorBlending.blendConstants[2] = 0.0f;
    colorBlending.blendConstants[3] = 0.0f;

    VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo pipelineLayoutInfo = {};
    pipelineLayoutInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineLayoutInfo.setLayoutCount = 1;
    pipelineLayoutInfo.pSetLayouts = &descriptorSetLayout;

    if (vkCreatePipelineLayout(device, &pipelineLayoutInfo, nullptr, &pipelineLayout) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create pipeline layout!");
    }

    VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipelineInfo = {};
    pipelineInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineInfo.stageCount = 2;
    pipelineInfo.pStages = shaderStages;
    pipelineInfo.pVertexInputState = &vertexInputInfo;
    pipelineInfo.pInputAssemblyState = &inputAssembly;
    pipelineInfo.pViewportState = &viewportState;
    pipelineInfo.pRasterizationState = &rasterizer;
    pipelineInfo.pMultisampleState = &multisampling;
    pipelineInfo.pColorBlendState = &colorBlending;
    pipelineInfo.layout = pipelineLayout;
    pipelineInfo.renderPass = renderPass;
    pipelineInfo.subpass = 0;
    pipelineInfo.basePipelineHandle = VK_NULL_HANDLE;

    if (vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(device, VK_NULL_HANDLE, 1, &pipelineInfo, nullptr, &graphicsPipeline) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create graphics pipeline!");
    }

    vkDestroyShaderModule(device, fragShaderModule, nullptr);
    vkDestroyShaderModule(device, vertShaderModule, nullptr);
}
```

Comment: The error seems clear. So, what\which renderpass do you specify when creating the `graphicsPipeline`? The error claims it is different render pass than the one you use for `vkCmdBeginRP`, and also it is incompatible.

Comment: @krOoze I added an edit showing how I create the `RenderPass`.

Comment: Yea, but how do you create the pipeline, and which render pass do you use in doing so?

Comment: PS: Also check which `vkCmdDrawIndexed` fails. Yours, or the one inserted by imgui? Maybe even try without imgui, if it works.

Comment: @krOoze I added the function used to create the GraphicsPipeline, I am pretty sure the `vkCmdDrawIndexed` which fails is the one created by ImGui. If I do create a different `RenderPass` do you happen to know how should it be setup for ImGui? And that means I need a completely different `GraphicsPipeline` also doesn't it? Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: Hm, simplest way to debug this would probably be to enable `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump`, and see where do the objects referenced in the error come from. If you say you create only one render pass, but the error says you have two, that is a weird discrepancy.

Comment: I'll look into `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump`. I guess the bindings provided by ImGui create another `RenderPass` behind the scenes when the ImGui window undocks.

Comment: In which case that would probably be their bug. The imgui asks for render pass when inited. And their example shows you should `vkCmdBegin` your renderpass, which means they should definitely not be using their own. Though after all you are using some experimental branch...

Comment: I have been pulling for a while waiting for it to be fixed, but I should probably start an issue on their repo. I don't have enough time to create an implementation by myself, or even to try and debug their code, either way thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem seems to happen just when you're using the multiview/docking feature in ImGUI.

When you enable multiview/docking feature, ImGUI creates by itself it's own render pass, pipeline and so on to handle all the ImGUI external windows, so the problem just show up when you drag the ImGUI window outside of the main window. As you might see at the [ImGUI vulkan implementation](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/docking/backends/imgui_impl_vulkan.cpp#L1504), when choosing the surface format for the internal render pass, it doesn't accept all formats. I don't know exactly why, but the possible formats accepted by the internal render pass are those in this section of the code. So basically, using the **VK_COLORSPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR** color space as the other pair of the match for the surfaceFormat, it returns the first option available for the format. The way I solved the problem is to select the format of the surface the same way it's implemented in ImGUI, or in other words, my surface returns **VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM** flag for my surface. Supposedly [this PR](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/issues/3522) solved this problem (and in the comments the guy made a reference to this issue).

the formats for ImGui goes:

```
const VkFormat requestSurfaceImageFormat[] = { VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8_UNORM, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8_UNORM };
```

Comment: I am marking this as the answer as this has pretty much been dead since I asked and does give some insights into the why and when it was fixed.